# How can I use OS X's Accessibility API to write acceptance tests for my applications?

Tags: cocoa, testing, cucumber, accessibility, macruby

I'm writing a GUI application in Cocoa.  I'd like to use Cucumber to write acceptance tests to continually verify that the application's features work.  I'm already writing the application in MacRuby.

Can I use the Accessibility API to click things and drag things around?  Where can I read about how to do such things?  I've found Apple's site to be relatively mum on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest checking out [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank). It uses the accessibility approach and has worked great for me so far!

Comment: Frank is only for iOS, isn't it?

Comment: @Peeja Yes. Could implement a similar solution if there isn't already one out there. I think the overall concept should be the same.